# SQL Developer: how to match two columns and leave blanks where no match is found?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to count the duplicates of one column compared to the master column. Whenever I query to count the duplicates and group by the two columns and the count it makes the row total go from 50,000 to 415,000 because it begins to look something like this:

`|Column1| Column2|Count(C1)|
 | Item1 | Item1  | 20     |
 | Item1 | Item2  | 20     |
 | Item1 | Item3  | 20     |`

How do I make it so it only reports item 1 from column 1 once and lines up item 2 and 3 from column 1 so that they are listed next to one another? Is there a way to leave blanks in column 1 so that if column 2 has item 15 but column 1 does not it'll leave a blank with a count of 0?

Comment: I think you want a combination of count distinct and case,but you have to clarify,add your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find Count of repeated column values from a detail table only if it is in Master table, below query should work.

```
select MasterTable.Column1,DetailTable.Column2, Count(DetailTable.Column2)  
  from 
     MasterTable  
     left outer join  
     DetailTable  
     on MasterTable.Column1=DetailTable.Column2  
group by MasterTable.Column1,DetailTable.Column2
```

Note: Assuming master table has unique value in Column1.

If you are looking for something else, could you explain your requirement little better with example table values and output you are looking for.